# xcode I want distance between buttons to change by auto layout

Tags: xcode, ios-autolayout

[image]

I am adapting my app from iphone8 to ipad by using auto layout.

I want to distances change as i drawn.

But using Horizontal Space Constraint isn't work in this case.

How can i solve my problem?

Comment: Do your buttons change size bed on screen size? If so, how are you setting the button sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want variable distance between buttons, you should avoid giving Horizontal space constraints. Instead

1. Give leading constraint to left box
2. Center horizontally the centre box
3. Give trailing constraint to right box

This should solve your issue.

[image: Left box constraints]
[image: Center box constraints]
[image: Right box constraints]

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I need to ask you more ;( That was a just sample. What if there are more buttons, How can I do this? In that case, that solution works too?

Comment: No. Then you have to apply solution not exactly like this but in principle it will remain same. Logic is, the left and right items you fix. And using a centre item you align the rest of them. When you have more you better do some math and manage the spacing accordingly. assign constraints via code.